# Expression error while trying to insert a JavaScript code into head section in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am trying to insert a JavaScript code snippet into the head section of the document but it's showing an expression error. I am using the Gatsby framework.

The code is

```
<Helmet>
   <script>
      var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];
      _paq.push(["disableCookies"]);
      _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
      _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
      (function() {
         var u="SITELINK"; //Error is on var
         _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
         _paq.push(['setSiteId', 'SITEID']);
         var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         g.async=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
      })(); //Error is on closing curly bracket
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

And the errors are on

1. "var" - "Expression expected just after the function() declared
2. Closing curly bracket of the function()

I have checked for any junk characters but it's clean.

Comment: Remember you are writing JSX and `{...}` has special meaning in JSX.

Comment: Re edit: `<head>` was correct. `<header>` is completely different.

Comment: @Quentin I wrote <head> first and then for some reason it was not showing. May be because I used tags.

Comment: Quick fix - The character code for { and } helped.